# java programs are displaying as SYSTEMin netstat -b results

Tags: java, windows, netstat

I am running same java application on two servers. Applications are deployed using TOMCAT.

When I verify using netstat -b to check whether its running properly or not, I can see that netstat results is showing SYSTEM instead of java.exe process in one of my server.

Why it is displaying SYSTEM instead of java.exe?

Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

server1:

```
[System] TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 lap80:0 LISTENING
```

server2:

```
[java.exe] TCP 0.0.0.0:8080 lap81:0 LISTENING
```

Thanks, susil

Answer (score 0):

Check the server which is showing as System, **is tomcat really running in that server?**, I mean some other process has got hold of 8080 port before tomcat had chance to start.